# MVC, should I be referencing additional classes from model or controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model, controller

I'm trying to learn a bit more about MVC. So far I am doing okay with smaller programs. For my purposes I have been keeping all the business logic and 'results' in my model. At the moment I have 4 classes, my main class, a view class and a model and controller class.

I'm now thinking of separating some of the business logic from my model class and putting it in a separate class. This is where I'm unsure of what the best practice would be. Should I be creating/referencing my new class in my model class or should I do it directly from my controller class.

I'm not sure if it helps much but this is my current controller class:

```
public class BrowseController {
private BrowseModel m_model;
private BrowseView m_view;

public BrowseController(BrowseModel model, BrowseView view) {
    m_model = model;
    m_view = view;

    view.addRunListener(new RunListener());
    view.addClearListener(new ClearListener());
}

class RunListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            start();            
    }
}

class ClearListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("clear");
        m_view.reset();
        m_model.reset();
    }
}

private void start(){
    SwingWorker<Void, Object[]> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Object[]>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            m_view.setStatus("Running");
            HashSet<String> urls = m_view.getTargetUrls();

            for (String url : urls){
                m_model.processUrl(url);

                publish(m_model.getResults());
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            m_view.setStatus(m_model.getStatus());
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Object[]> resultList) {
            for(Object[] resultRow : resultList){
                m_view.setResult(resultRow);
            }

        }

    };

    worker.execute();       
}

}
```

If there's anything else I should be providing just let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to me, if it's pure data business objects you can add it to your model.
In case you're thinking of some handling on data then I would prefer to add it to the controller.

That's just my point of view ; let's see another ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you an answer (thus i cant tell you the best practise for your specific example ... even couldn't if you would provide the rest of the source since i am a software engineer and not a software architect) to point out some thoughts/ topics that come in play here. So watch out for the **keywords**, the more you read/ learn about them the more you become a software architect and can answer such questions and proving it by pointing to the according source of information.

First of all i agree with User neoboard about business objects (that represent data to be displayed in the view) belong to the model part of the MVC model (still i have not read the works of **Trygve Reenskaug** nor from the **gang of four [Gof]**). When it comes to your business logic as faar as i remember there is no specification in the MVC model where to put it (due to the model is language independend in general and specific implementations of it vary from language to language) but most oftenly its considered to reside in the controller part for high level languages like Java.

When it comes to MVC what i remember from school/ study days is that the big point of this **design pattern** is about having the model and the view part seperated from each other as good as possible (standard school sample "so you can exchange the view without any changes to the model"). To take it to a higher level lets say you want to archive **loose coupling** of your objects to make them as reusable as possible.

Now even if you follow patterns like **Observer** somewhere in your source you have to put the wires together (controller part) and expecially as a beginner see some conflicts between different patterns (which as faar as i know can never be solved completely).

There comes in the concept of **Association** and **Composition** which when mixed with **Abstraction** and **Specialisation** and language features like **interfaces** and **abstract classes** (Java) allow you to have very generic code where different components are theoreticialy exchanged very easy.

Now thats pretty much what i want you to tell from the theory part (better have a look at a good book to make sure you get valid information).

Another part is how its done in practise. In Java EE where i work for example loose coupling in the end is mostly archived by **dependency injection** where one of your class just holds a reference of a interface type and gets the implementation object instance at runtime by the EE container (Websphere, JBoss, Glassfish etc.). Also the big design patterns are not self-wired in general but implemented with the use of frameworks that should enforce and/or support **best practises** and design patterns to mention just a few parts about how its done whne the theory ends.

Still thats some pretty sweet theory but man i can tell you even Swiss bank systems can be hard to maintain because software engineers like i am have done a little bit to much of the architecture part and architectures these days oftenly dont know enoth from the engineering part while the managers dont get sh...t at all and dont see the point of "wasting" money on the design that much (starts to change but its a slow process..).

In case you are just starting to learn Java ("start"... i cared about MVC like after 2 years of Java) dont be afraid to do things the wrong way but try to keep in touch with the few people in a company that can point out the wrong part and explain how to do better (and are not just glad it was cheap and runs properly).

When some day working on the big projects try not just to finish the tasks but to understand why something is build the way it is (nothing better if you have time for it) and even if it follows patterns allow yourself to ask if it realy makes your live as a software engineer easier.

I now have about 13 years of Java experience and worked in the financial-, public transport- and arms industry where they have the realy big Java EE applications... none of them would have needed even one software engineer like i am if these concepts would be that easy to apply or there would be a easy way to verify if its done the right way when it comes to a certain size/ complexity.

I hope i could help you in a bit another way than directly on your current source level and you can fogive me the many spelling errors (swiss german is my mothers tongue ... we dont even have a official grammar for that...). Keep on the good work!